# Why does the guard of my sword glow when it shouldn't

Tags: rendering, cycles-render-engine, materials, light, lighting

I am working on a final render for my little sword project I have been working on, but this issue perplexes me.

Essentially, when I render the scene in cycles, the guard of the centre sword glows. Initially, I thought perhaps there was accidentally emissions on the material, then I thought maybe the metal was reflecting light inwards, creating a glow effect, but I have disproven that too.

I know I could change the lighting setup to make it less obvious, but my overall goal was to get four shadows as if there are four ceiling lights, and increasing the strength seems to remove the shadows.

Here is the file: https://we.tl/t-FPs1yar0nu

Here is a reduced file:

[image]

This is what the render currently looks like:

[image: Three swords]

Everything removed except the guard and lights:

[image: Everything removed except the guard and lights]

Everything removed except for the guard:

[image: Everything removed except for the guard]

Node setup for metal inside the guard (the glowing grey part):

[image]

Node Setup for the Green of the guard:

[image]

Blue light:

[image]

Red light:

[image]

Lighting setup:

[image]

Light from only underneath:

[image]

Any help is appreciated!

EDIT:

Here is the result after implementing the solution

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure there's anything anormal here, actually all your light directions converge towards the handle so it makes it light very bright

Comment: @moonboots I thought this at first, but reducing it to one light and moving it around still leaves it glowing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe moonboots and Rich Sedman are both partially right.

First, this geometry just converges light, and your roughness is generally low, so it will be a bit bright there no matter what.

In the Outliner, enter this menu:

[image]

and you can go through all of your materials.  Clamp any add nodes or change them to mix if they feed into the principled color input.  It's easier to do it from this menu because a lot of your objects have multiple material slots.

Once I changed a few add nodes to mix the brightness got a bit better.  This will change your material colors, so beware.

Comment: Thank you! It still isn't perfect but I like it much better now

Comment: I think if you sample it enough it will look pretty natural.

Answer (score 1):

Very difficult to say from the description. To track down the cause you can do something like the following :

Remove all the lights and world illumination, does the glow disappear? If not then there must be emission somewhere - hide everything then switch them on one by one in the outliner to narrow down which mesh is causing the problem.

If disabling the lights also disables the glow then the problem is with one of your lights or you have a material that’s effectively amplifying the incident light - disable each material until you find the one causing it and then post details and we can try and point out the cause.

Comment: I have done as you asked and added images to show what is happening. I'm still lost as to what to do. Should I include images of the light and material details?

Comment: Yes please - the nodes of the materials would be useful. Also, please add a brief description for each of the images - is the first one without illumination?

Comment: Okay I will work on that. I wrote captions for the images but I guess that does not show up

Comment: I have added the requested information. Remember there is also a download link if you wish to check it yourself

Comment: I can’t check properly right now, but my suspicion is that your material ‘Add’ node is resulting in a color with values greater than 1.0. This would result in a surface that effectively amplifies any light that hits it. For concave surface this is amplified even more as it bounces light off itself as it will increase in intensity on each ‘bounce’. Just an idea at the moment - thought I’d mention it so you could investigate further. Try disconnecting one of the color ramps or bypass the Add and see if that helps.

Comment: Actually, best way to prove this out is to enable the ‘Clamp’ on the Add node.

Comment: that's actually a good thought, I'll give it a try. I have an exam until 9:30 tho so won't have any updates until then :)

Comment: I tried what you suggested without much success. Im thinking its just the way the lights are set up that's doing it

Comment: Now I don't think its that either! I added a light underneath and removed the others and its the same result! This is driving me nuts!

Comment: Hmmmm. I've downloaded your file and tried a few things. I'll work on it when I can. Can you provide a cut down file that still shows the problem? Please upload it to https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and paste the link to your question (it's a permanent blend file hosting site for this site).

Comment: I have added a reduced file. Glow still persists